# Copy files while rearranging folder structure

Tags: linux, command-line, find, copy

On my Synology station I have a huge photo archive with the following structure:

```
/volume1/photo/2019/
                +--January
                    +--@eaDir (hidden folder)
                         +--001.jpg (folder)
                               +-- THUMB.jpg
                         +--002.jpg (folder)
                               +-- THUMB.jpg
                    +--001.jpg (image file)
                    +--002.jpg (image file)
```

I want to copy the thumbnails (not the actual images) to a different volume but keep the basic folder structure like this:

```
/volume2/thumbnails/2019/
                +--January
                    +--001.jpg (former thumbnail)
                    +--002.jpg (former thumbnail)
```

What I tried was:

```
find /volume1/photo/2019/ -name '*PREVIEW.jpg' -exec cp --parents \{\} /volume2/target/ \;
```

But this still keeps the hidden `@eaDir` folder and I cannot figure out how to omit them.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My hint is the bold text in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1553188/432690). Can you take it from here? You need to decide if you `find` thumbnails and let the script determine the corresponding name, or you `find` big files and let the script locate the corresponding thumbnail for each. In any case it's about manipulating paths, strings stored as shell variables.