# Accessing parent and grandparent directory from linux find and passing to xargs

Tags: linux, bash, find, imagemagick, xargs

I'm trying to do a batch imagemagick conversion on all tiffs in directories.

The structure of the directories looks like:

```
test    
    123
       456
          image.tif

    256
       857
          anotherimage.tif
```

I'm trying to use find to locate all the images, and then pass those into xargs for imagemagick to convert to jp2. The output filename would be a combination of the granparent and parent directory names, so in the example above, `image.tif` would be converted to `123456.jp2`.

I've got the `find` working ok, but just can't get the correct combination of imagemagick and find params to achieve what I need. Here's the find with xargs. The {grandparentdir} and {parentdir} are placeholders for the bit I'm missing!

```
find /var/tmp/test -type f \( -name "*.tif" -o -name "*.TIF" -o -name "*.tiff" -o -name "*.TIFF" \) -mtime -1 | xargs convert -quality 100 \var\tmp\test\{granparentdir}{parentdir}.jp2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a shell from `find -exec` and manipulate the paths there:

```
find /var/tmp/test -type f \
   \( -name "*.tif" -o -name "*.TIF" -o -name "*.tiff" -o -name "*.TIFF" \) \
   -mtime -1 \
   -exec sh -c '
      for f do
         parent="$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")"
         grandparent="$(basename "$(dirname "$(dirname "$f")")")"
         printf "%s\n" "$grandparent$parent.jp2"
         # convert   -- whatever arguments you want
      done
   ' sh-find {} +
```

I used `dirname` and `basename` in a non-optimal way. You can use shell parameter expansion instead (`${f%/*}` etc.) and e.g. `realpath` if needed.

The point is **you run a shell and you can do anything in it**.

In my example the whole shell code is single-quoted (this is because any expansion by the outer shell is potentially unsafe, the inner shell will parse the result). If you need single-quotes inside the code then proper quoting will get somewhat complicated. In this case instead of `-exec sh -c '…' sh-find {} +` consider `-exec sh ./script {} +` where `script` is a file containing the code. Inside the file you quote like in any other shell script.

If you need Bash, use `-exec bash`. Use whatever shell you need. Or something else. If you need Python, use `-exec python`. This approach is quite powerful.

---

More information:

- [How to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618)
- About the mysterious `sh-find`: [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690).

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful for others. I ended up splitting the command into two:

1. transform the files first
2. Move/rename afterwards

**1. Transform using mogrify**

```
find /var/tmp/test -type f -not -name "*.thumb*" -not -name "*.500x500*" \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.JPG" -o -name "*.png" -o -name "*.PNG" -o -name "*.tif" -o -name "*.TIF" -o -name "*.tiff" -o -name "*.TIFF" -o -name "*.bmp" -o -name "*.BMP" \) | xargs mogrify -format jp2
```

**2.Rename and move the file to a location of my choice**

```
find /var/tmp/test -type f -name "*.jp2" -execdir bash -c \ 'old="{}"; new="$(cd ..; basename -- "$PWD")$(basename -- "$PWD").jp2"; mv "$old" /var/tmp/test/"$new"' - {} \;
```